# Unreferenced vs referenced use of object

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a case where I have a form "MyForm.cs" that I have created and setup with the designer. I need it just to inform the user about an error and after he clicks its "OK" button that form closes and I never need it again, unless the same error occurs, which will be rare (it's a handled error).

I can go about showing the form in two ways:
Unreferenced
`new MyForm().ShowDialog();`

Referenced
`MyForm myForm = new MyForm();`
`myForm.ShowDialog();`

Since I won't be reusing the form I'm thinking giving it a name isn't needed and it would be better to go with the unreferenced syntax?

Is there any benefit of using one instead of the other?

Comment: As long as `using System.Windows.Forms` used, it recognizes `Form` class instantiation so that both statements are valid (I think there's no other benefit rather than readability, you can use `var form = new Form()` to simplify declaration).

Comment: If you really need it only once you may throw the reference to the form away. However be aware that using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` expects to call `Dispose` on the form when done, so you should store the reference into a variable.

Comment: I'm not an expert in WinForm, but you should avoid instantiating the Form in another class, as a best OOP practice. I assume you would need to set up the Dialog with text to be reused correct? So I would either suggest that you create a static factory method on the Form class and pass the setup parameters there (like the text of the dialog) or doing it in the .ShowDialog() instead.

Comment: @Steve, I am using other controls inside the form to show more information that a MessageBox can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157550/discussion-between-steve-and-j-doe).

Comment: @Gugas (apologies, I deleted my previous comment by mistake), I'm afraid I'm quite a novice and do not understand what you mean - do you mean I shouldn't call "MyForm.cs" from another form but instead make a factory method in "MyForm.cs"? How would I go about showing "MyForm.cs" from another form then?

Comment: What you call "Anonymous" is really "Unreferenced" and what you call "Named" is just "Referenced". You're not "naming" it with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "anonymous" is just an instance of a type for which you throw away the reference when you´re done with that instance. You may do this if you´re sure you won´t do anything with the instance. In your case you need to call `Dispose` on your form which is why throwing the reference away is a bad idea. You surely need a reference to the instance you want to dispose. As from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aw58wzka(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the
>   Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used, or the form
>   is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your
>   application.

If on the other side you´d call `Show` the `Dispose`-method will automatically get called when done, so you *can* throw the reference away.

So you can write this:

```
using(var f = new MyForm())
{
    f.ShowDialog(...);
    // do something with the form
}
```

Aside from the above storing a reference into a variable is allmost allways good idea as it imprves the readability. This is every user of your code understands what a statement does when it has a clear name describing its purpose.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you will probably dispose the dialog from within itself no? So you probably do not need to save a reference to Dispose it later. P.S. I'm an Android and Xamarin.Android developer so I might be mistaken or missing some logic.

Comment: @Gugas: how you will dipose the form from within itself? No, the caller should dispose it when he's finished with it and above code does this. At the end of the scope of the `using`-statement the form is disposed.

Comment: Ah-h-h-h, thank you I didn't know "ShowDialog()" does not automatically dispose it. I thought if it went out of scope the Garbage Collector would take it out but I will use `using`.

Comment: @J.Doe Important point: The garbage collector only cleans up memory - it does NOT clean up things like Windows Handles, which is why you must call `Dispose()` explictly or implicity via `using`.